# X2Go client can not start after enabling Alt+Tab keyshortcut combination

Tags: client-server

I want to enable the use of `Alt+Tab` keys combination on X2Go client. So I did the settings described on [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150211175916/http://www.terheyden.com/blog/?p=202&cpage=1#comment-279). Now,  each time I click on the icon of X2Go I get this message:

> Can not start X server
>
> Please check your installation

I uninstalled and reinstalled the client, but still have the same issue.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by changing the actual path to the `vcxsrv.exe` in registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Obviously Nice\x2goclient\settings
```

Comment: Never would have thought that was needed.  Nice!